# how to apply animations for different views sequentially?

Tags: ios, core-animation

There are four views on which I need to apply animation.
If an user tap button, the animation is that `view1` should hide for 1 second, and then `view2`, then `view3`, then `view4`.

The problem is that how to apply animations in different views with sequence?

I need to use Core Animation to finish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` method where the completion block calls a method which runs the next animation (and similarly its completion block starts the next part of the chain).

Answer (score 0):

Nesting Animations can help you achieve what you want.

Refer [Animations in UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html)

```
- (IBAction)yoiurButtonClickAction:(id)sender{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay: 0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         _view1.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                               delay: 0.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              _view1.alpha = 1.0;
                                              _view2.alpha = 0.0;
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                                    delay: 0.0
                                                                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                                               animations:^{
                                                                   _view2.alpha = 1.0;
                                                                   _view3.alpha = 0.0;
                                                               }
                                                               completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                                   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                                                         delay: 0.0
                                                                                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                                                                    animations:^{
                                                                                        _view3.alpha = 1.0;
                                                                                        _view4.alpha = 0.0;
                                                                                    }
                                                                                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                                                        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                                                                                              delay: 0.0
                                                                                                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                                                                                         animations:^{
                                                                                                             _view4.alpha = 1.0;

                                                                                                         }
                                                                                                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                                                                                         }];
                                                                                    }];
                                                               }];
                                          }];
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

h.

```
NSInteger currentView;
UIView *view1, *view2, *view3, *view4;
```

m.

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

currentView = 1;

view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 100)];
[view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:view1];

view2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 80, 100)];
[view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.view addSubview:view2];

view3 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 80, 100)];
[view3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.view addSubview:view3];

view4 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 0, 80, 100)];
[view4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[self.view addSubview:view4];
```

}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

```
[self runAnimation];
```

}

-(UIView *)viewForAnimation:(NSInteger)index
{

```
switch (index)
{
    case 1:
        return view1;
    case 2:
        return view2;
    case 3:
        return view3;
    case 4:
        return view4;
}
return view1;
```

}

-(void)runAnimation
{

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^
 {
     [self viewForAnimation:currentView].hidden = YES;
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     currentView++;
     if(currentView < 5)
         [self performSelector:@selector(runAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
 }
 ];
```

}